# Running Javascript inside a simplemodal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, simplemodal

I'm trying to add scripts to a modal ([simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)) jquery plugin but they won't run, is this functionality simply not available when running in the modal or am I missing something.

Here's how I'm calling simplemodal:

```
$('#modal').modal({
  onClose: function (dialog) {
    $App.setLocation('#/');
    $.modal.close();
  }
});
```

and here's the html of the modal, which includes the addthis script (i've taken out the real username for posting here):

```
<div class="article clearfix">
  <div class="article-post">
    <h2 class="title">{{header}}</h2>
    <p class="date">Posted in {{feed_source}}, {{date}}</p>
    <ul class="tags clearfix">
      <li><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="body">
      {{{body}}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="single-article-comments" class="article-comments">
    <h3 class="comments-header">Comments:</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar clearfix">
  <div class="sidebar-inner">
    <p class="sidebar-logo">Logo Text</p>
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li><a href="#single-article-comments" class="sidebar-comment tooltip" title="Comment on this article">Comment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/rate/{{id}}" title="Rate" class="sidebar-rate tooltip">Rate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/slate/{{id}}" title="Slate" class="sidebar-slate tooltip">Slate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/report/{{id}}" title="Report Abuse / Flag as Inappropriate" class="sidebar-report tooltip">Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Email">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Tweet">Tweet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Facebook Like">Like</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sidebar-action-addthis addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="http://www.allaboutmidleton.ie/#/article/{article_id}" addthis:title="Tweet by {user}" addthis:description="{tweet}">
      <li><a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" class="tooltip addthis_button_email" title="Email to a Friend"><img src="/assets/img/ico-email.png" width="26" height="23" border="0" alt="Email" /></a></li>
      <li><a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a></li>
      <li><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=username"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    <div class="sidebar-ads">
      <ul class="advertising-ad-list">
        <li><a href="" class="ad">Advertisement</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="ad">Advertisement</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="ad">Advertisement</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All of this code works fine outside of the modal. Does anyone know a way to run the script inside the modal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is `$App.setLocation('#/');` doing?

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, but intended the `onClose` callback to be used mainly for closing animations.

My suggestion would be to use the `onShow` callback and bind your own function to the "close" event. For example:

```
$('#modal').modal({
  onShow: function (dialog) {
    $('.close', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
      $App.setLocation('#/');
      $.modal.close();
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for replying, $App.setLocation('#/'); is a SammyJS function which simply routes the Application back to the homepage, when somebody clicks on a link the modal pops up but the location hash also changes to #/article/1234 (where 1234 is the article id). Closing the dialog works fine for me, my problem is that I can't run any scripts inside the modal, I'm trying to embed an AddThis script but it doesn't load.

Comment: ... I just emailed you a link :)

Comment: I think the issue is that you need to initialize any scripts after the modal is created (in the onShow callback).

Answer (score 0):

SimpleModal is more powerful than, I would like to believe, even Eric Martin knows.

1. Create your modal hidden div within your main document;
2. Create WHATEVER FULL HTML/ASP/JAVASCRIPT page you want to process in that modal;
3. Load the hidden div with the HTML/ASP/JAVASCRIPT page using jquery.load();
4. Display the modal

Comment: Unfortunately, using jQuery.load() can cause issues with the way container dimension and position values are determined. As of now, I prefer to use jQuery.get(url, data, callback) and then use the data in the callback for the modal() call.

Comment: So far, in three "applications", I haven't had the issue you mention or haven't been able to identify if that problem occurs. I haven't looked at jquery.get but I ask: does jquery.get load javascript/asp without any problems? (this is not a competition). I too use the $.get or $.post for displaying modals data but, when I want further processing (from within the answer page), I use jquery.load. To date, no problems.