# Posting to Tinybox2 modal from form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I am using Tinybox on a Codeigniter site for some functions like registering, login, viewing images, etc....

On the homepage of the site there is a small registration box that allows a user to enter a company email and company name. On submit this should then present a modal window with the full registration form. The Company Email and Company Name fields should already be filled in with whatever the user entered in the previous form.

I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Here is the code I am using -

Initial registration form -

```
<form>
  <div class="tab">
    <label for="preCompany">Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="preCompany" name="preCompany"/>
<br/>
<label for="preEmail">Corporate Email:</label>
<input type="text" size="20" id="preEmail" name="preEmail"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Continue..." onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'/register.php'}); return false;" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is the full form that should open in a modal window and have some fields prepopulated -

```
<?php echo form_open('register/register_form'); ?>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" id="email" name="email"/>
  <br />
  <label for="company">Company:</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" id="company" name="company"/>
  <br/>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" size="20" id="password" name="password"/>
  <br/>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" id="name" name="name"/>
  <br/>
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" id="phone" name="phone"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: steps: 1. after filling out the form, trigger tinybox. 2. Store the name and email in two variable and then put the values in a fly form. 3. Show the form in tinybox. 4. you are done!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I figured something like this would be the way but the only problem is I can't work out how to do it in code. Could you help me with that?  Thanks

Comment: tinybox isn't a good tool for this to be honest. None the less, using jquery will make this way smoother and reliable. is jquery an option? _biased user here. I love Jquery!_

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I wanted to avoid JQuery as I don't use it elsewhere on this project and didn't like the idea of using it just for this. But I did come up with a solution. After reading your post yesterday I did a bit more digging and found a way that works, I'll post it as an answer and it would be great if you could let me know what you think of it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works. I'm not sure if this is a good solution but it has held up under a few tests and it should be cross-browser compatible.
I found a few different sites that pointed me in the right direction and cobbled together an answer using what they said. Unfortunately I got them on my work computer so have no references to give here but I'll post them as an edit later.

Here is my new code:

```
<form method="link" action="/register">
  <div class="tab">
    <label for="preCompany">Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="preCompany" name="preCompany" onblur="var preCompany = document.getElementById('preCompany');"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="preEmail">Corporate Email:</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="preEmail" name="preEmail" onblur="var preEmail = document.getElementById('preEmail');"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue..." onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'/register'}); return false;" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically what I am doing here is setting a variable each time the user fills in one of the input boxes and then clicks away from that box. The tinybox script is called once the submit button is clicked. The two variables are global so can now be used by the Tinybox modal. The two variables can be empty.

Here is the code that is called in the modal window. It is also the regular registration page code so it seems that the variables do not need to be set at all and no error occurs.

```
<img src="/img/bg.gif" alt="" onload="document.getElementById('email').value = preEmail.value; document.getElementById('company').value = preCompany.value; this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />

<?php echo form_open('register/register_form'); ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="40" id="email" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="company">Company Name:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="40" id="company" name="company"/></td>
    </tr>
......
```

The sites that I referred to earlier explain this in a much better way but basically  a modal window does not allow Javascript to be run so you have to force it. The recommended way was using something called `eval()` but I ended up using this `<img />` version which apparently works across browser and without any issues. All that happens is the img tag runs the Javascript which fills in the two inputs on the form with the contents of the variables that have just been set. A bit of JS then removes the img tag. IMPORTANT - The image referenced in the img tag needs to exist.

I'll post the sites where I find this info later which may help to explain what is happening here better than I can.

Thanks to [itachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164513/itachi) for the replies and help.

EDIT - 
This page got me started on the path I went down - [Tinybox does not run (eval) javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456389/tinybox-does-not-run-eval-javascript-code)

This page helped some more - [Running Javascript inside a simplemodal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041288/running-javascript-inside-a-simplemodal-window)

And this one gave me the answer for using an img tag to run the JS in the modal window - [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: i don't know how tiny box works in details but if it can load DOM elements, here's a nicer solution. On the page load, 1. load the form(the big one) with `display:hidden` in css. 2. On blur/submit, put those two values into the respective fields of tat big form. 3. After that, load the whole form in tinybox.

Comment: Hi, I found some help on this on the Tinybox page and apparently showing a div in Tinybox is not part of the functionality. There is a workaround but I'm happy to stick with this way for now. Thanks again for your help.